# Regexp to match account number

Tags: regex, oracle

I need to match multiple variations of accounting number to exclude it from results. Here is example account number `202098101001003000011`
The main condition is match `20209` at the beginning and 8 digits after it. And then goes options.

Here is my regexp

```
'^20209[[:digit:]]{8}(000|0000010|0600000|040|070|030)'
```

It works fine, but i need to add last condition - match `030` only if there is 0000 (four zeros) after it. I can not understand how to do it correctly.

I use oracle 11 and regexp_instr function.

Comment: Your example account number does not have a `030` with `0000` (four zeros) after it.

Comment: Because i don't know how to write it :) I know how to add one zero - 030[^(0)]

Comment: I'm saying the example (valid) account number that you gave does not match the conditions you specified- namely a `030` followed by `0000`, which would be `0300000`.

Comment: Ah, now i understand :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following *regex* :

```
^20209[[:digit:]]{8}[[:digit:]]+(?=0{4})
```